# How do I add a date of birth UIDatePicker to UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, date

I request the users date of birth on the sign up screen of my application. I can't figure out how to get a date of birth `UIDatePicker` to display. I tried using the following code but it only displays the date and time:

```
 UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
_textBirthday.inputView = dp;
```

Also, how would I set it so it only accepts users born after a certain year?

Comment: `minimumData` property of `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: and what do you mean by *it only displays the date and time*? what do you want it to display?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) in the .h file of your view controller make sure you assign textfield delegate:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and also have an IBOutlet of the birthday Textfield

2) declare a date picker as a class variable to make it accessible from all different methods in class. in the .m file do the following after import and before implementation:

```
@interface YourViewController () {
UIDatePicker *datePicker;
}
@end
```

3) in viewdidload:

```
// make the textfield its own delegate
self.BirthdateTextfield.delegate = self;

// alloc/init your date picker, and (optional) set its initial date
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]]; //this returns today's date

// theMinimumDate (which signifies the oldest a person can be) and theMaximumDate (defines the youngest a person can be) are the dates you need to define according to your requirements, declare them:

// the date string for the minimum age required (change according to your needs) 
NSString *maxDateString = @"01-Jan-1996";
// the date formatter used to convert string to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// the specific format to use
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
// converting string to date
NSDate *theMaximumDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: maxDateString];

// repeat the same logic for theMinimumDate if needed

// here you can assign the max and min dates to your datePicker 
[datePicker setMaximumDate:theMaximumDate]; //the min age restriction 
[datePicker setMinimumDate:theMinimumDate]; //the max age restriction (if needed, or else dont use this line)

// set the mode
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

// update the textfield with the date everytime it changes with selector defined below
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// and finally set the datePicker as the input mode of your textfield
[self.BirthdateTextfield setInputView:datePicker];
```

4) in same .m file, define the selector that will update textfield each time the date picker changes:

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender {
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.BirthdateTextfield.inputView;
    self.BirthdateTextfield.text = [self formatDate:picker.date];
}
```

5) last but not least, this is the method called before assigning the date to the textfield.text (textfield.text needs a string not a date):

```
- (NSString *)formatDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return formattedDate;
}
```

enjoy coding!

Comment: oh my bad! its a habit of always using a singleton helping class called "Helper" in all my view controllers for easy access of those common methods.. in this case formatDate takes a NSDate and returns NSString. i'll edit my answer to include the method so that you can include it in your view controller

Comment: @carlos16196 Thanks for the detailed answer, unfortunately I get some errors with the code i.imgur.com/0EXr9HP.png

Comment: no problem @George, i have just updated my answer to really include as much details as you might need to solve the errors you got. they are all basically just a matter of declarations and defining variables. hope my updated answer will make more sense. and please come back to vote answer once your code works out.

Comment: @carlos16196 Nearly working, thanks. For some reason *theMaximumDate isn't being called and I don't understand why. Any ideas? Thanks. http://i.imgur.com/qMIECUQ.png

Comment: indeed.. i just wrote this on the go and didnt test it, actually its just a small mistake, i had a code with [NSDate date] to set today's date as the maximum. now we dont need [NSDate date] anymore, just setMaximumDate:theMaximumDate. i edited the code. everything should run perfectly now.

Comment: @carlos16196 Thanks, its working! Just one last thing. When select a date it shows up in the text field like a password, all black dots. Any idea why?

Comment: only property that would result in such behavior i know of is the secureTextEntry value of a textfield which we would use for passwords. check in your interface builder if you didnt check it by mistake in the attributes inspector tab, or search your code and make sure you didnt mix up birthdate textfield with password textfield. you could also force that property to NO in viewDidAppear like the following: 
    self.BirthdateTextfield.secureTextEntry = NO;

Comment: I'm sorry, but why do we need to set delegate for UITextField?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code you will get an output automatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.dobTextField setInputView:datePicker];
}

-(void) dateTextField:(id)sender{
 UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.dobTextField.inputView;
[picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *eventDate = picker.date;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
self.dobTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];
}
```

**Here is the Swift 4 code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  showDatePicker()
}

//MARK: Show Date Picker
func showDatePicker(){
    //Formate Date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    //ToolBar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar();
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    //done button & cancel button
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker))

    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton,spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)

    // add toolbar to textField
    dateOfBirthTxtFldRef.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    // add datepicker to textField
    dateOfBirthTxtFldRef.inputView = datePicker
}

@objc func donedatePicker(){
    //For date formate
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    dateOfBirthTxtFldRef.text! = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    //dismiss date picker dialog
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func cancelDatePicker(){
    //cancel button dismiss datepicker dialog
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `datePickerMode` to `UIDatePickerModeDate`.

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

> [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode): The date picker displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the locale setting. An example of this mode is [ November | 15 | 2007 ].
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.